# R - Excluding rows with a specific amount of zeroes in different sets of columns from the same data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   A1  A2  A3  B1  B2  B3  C1  C2  C3
X  00  10  00  10  00  11  00  00  00
Y  00  00  00  20  00  00  00  00  00
Z  00  00  00  29  30  00  50  42  38
```

First, I want to assess which samples (`A, B, C`) have more than one column different than zero. For X, for instance, A would be false, B would be true and C would be false.

Then, I want to keep the rows that have at least ONE sample (`A, B or C`) returning TRUE for the earlier code. That would mean my new data frame would have only rows X (sample B is true) and Z (samples B and C are true).

This could be done separately or in one line of code, if possible. As long as the final result is the same (rows like Y excluded)

Comment: Are these values numbers or text?  Numbers typically don't display double zeros.

Comment: They're numbers. One zero only in the actual data frame. The double zeroes in here are OCD-related.

Comment: To keep what you've got, `df[colSums(aggregate(t(df), list(substr(names(df), 1, 1)), function(x){sum(x != '00') > 1})[-1]) > 0, ]`. To move to a tidier data structure, `library(tidyverse); df %>% rownames_to_column('var') %>% gather(sample, value, -var) %>% separate(sample, c('sample', 'obs'), 1) %>% group_by(var, sample) %>% filter(sum(value != '00') > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

This will group all columns that start with a similar letter and are trailed by a number.

```
# data set used
df1 <- data.frame(A1=rep(0,3), A2=c(10,0,0), A3=rep(0,3), B1=c(10,20,29), B2=c(0,0,30), B3=c(11,0,0), C1=c(0,0,50), C2=c(0,0,42), C3=c(0,0,38))
rownames(df1) <- c("X", "Y", "Z")

# define column groups and count values greater than zero
col.samp <- unique(gsub("[0-9]", "", colnames(df1)))
m1 <- sapply(col.samp, function(x) rowSums(df1[grep(paste0("^", x), colnames(df1))] > 0))

df1[rowSums(m1 > 0) > 1, ]

  A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 C1 C2 C3
X  0 10  0 10  0 11  0  0  0
Z  0  0  0 29 30  0 50 42 38
```